# how update list of methods after WSDL update

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have tests in java to check web service. WSDL was changed and some methods where added and modified. I have generated java code from WSDL. How can I update list of methods in java (previously generated)? Is it possible to do it automaticaly?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what changed in the WSDL and what your code contains. See here for issues caused by changing a web service's contract: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657976/how-to-change-a-top-down-web-service-without-overwriting-existing-code

Comment: Thanks, but this post is a bit general. I'm interested in how can I generate new java code from wsdl (or update), because currently I have just existing project and never do this before. As I understand code was generated using JAX-WS. But I do not know details how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't happen automatically.  There are various ways to do this, but I do it using wsimport.  wsimport comes with the jdk, so you likely have it already:

```
wsimport <wsdl location>
```

where  is a url or file pointing to the wsdl.   You'll get compiled class files in the current directory which you can build a jar with to add to your project.

If you do this often enough, you can automate with an ant task (or various other options)

Comment: Is it possible to get a source files?

Comment: No source is needed for this.  Go to a command prompt or shell and type "wsimport"

Comment: I understand, I do this and got a list of compiled class files, but I can't look on code of those files. So is it possible to get java source files equivalent to whose compiled java class files? Sorry if it is silly question, but I'm new in all this. Also could you explain or give some link how to  build a jar this list of classes?

Comment: Yes, use -keep when you call wsimport.   [This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) will help you to create the jar: