# Is SOAP a verifiable or "type safe" API format compared to JSON?

Tags: json, soap

Today I heard someone state that SOAP and XML is like a 'type safe' way of defining an API, in that the message format adheres to a WSDL specification and can be validated.

This is in contrast to RESTful APIs where the message format has no way of being validated (is there a way to validate it?) as it's "dynamically typed" like Javascript.

The opinion was that it's not as easy to break a SOAP API as it is a RESTful one - I guess by virtue of the fact that you need to explicitly change the wsdl specification, whereas you could more easily change the REST JSON API?

Is this technically correct?

Comment: Maybe this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111646/restful-services-wsdl-equivalent . You can make a rest api more like a soap api if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

> Is SOAP a verifiable or “type safe” API format compared to JSON?

This depends on what you understand by ["type safe"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) but in the context of this question I must say that "type safe" does not have anything to do with how you send the data, via SOAP XML or REST JSON. XML isn't more "type safe" than JSON, or the other way.

I will not mention the similarities and differences between XML and JSON, you'll find plenty material online, but (simplistically speaking) they are both ways to represent data in a text format. Let's take a type `Person` and represent `John Doe` both ways:

```
<person>
   <firstName>John</firstName>
   <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</person>

{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

They are both identical but represented differently. If you send them to a SOAP and REST service respectively, and the service, for example, expect also a mandatory `id` property , then both will fail. They will not be "type safe" because they won't match **the actual type the service is expecting** which also contains the `id`.

> [...] SOAP and XML is like a 'type safe' way of defining an API, in that the message format adheres to a WSDL specification and can be validated.
>
> This is in contrast to RESTful APIs where the message format has no way of being validated [...]

A WSDL is a way to describe a SOAP web service just like WADL ([if you care for that thing](http://bitworking.org/news/193/Do-we-need-WADL)) is a way to describe a REST service. Both say what the service expects as input and emits as output. The exchanged data should conform to the WSDL/WADL, that's the idea in fact, but it's not the WSDL/WADL that enforces that the data is "type safe", it's the service itself.

The SOAP service must validate the XML data just like the RESTful service must validate the JSON data. The SOAP service isn't better than the REST service just because it uses XML instead of JSON. By the way, JSON is just a representation, you can have XML exchanged instead and that doesn't make it all of a sudden "type safe". **The service needs to make sure the data is valid and "type safe".**

> The opinion was that it's not as easy to break a SOAP API as it is a RESTful one - I guess by virtue of the fact that you need to explicitly change the wsdl specification, whereas you could more easily change the REST JSON API?

In fact it's just as easy to [break a SOAP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657976/how-to-change-a-top-down-web-service-without-overwriting-existing-code) as it is a RESTful one. If breaking changes are made to the WSDL then that breaks clients that were generated from the WSDL. This problem will happen for WADL generated REST clients also, it's exactly the same thing. RESTful client [should be more flexible in fact](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven), but a breaking change is a breaking change.

So to put a long story short, no, SOAP is not more verifiable or “type safe” as compared to JSON. Type safety is enforced by the web service, be it SOAP or REST, having it another way is just sloppy. The server should always make sure the clients send valid data.

Comment: Yeah, but JSON doesn't usually come with a schema which can validate the structure, whereas WSDL contains a schema which can validate the XML.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: There is also a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) [with implementations](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html) for most popular languages.

Comment: _wide_ implementation?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: the libs are there and allow you to validate JSON with a Schema (not that you absolutely need a Schema to do validation, which you are somehow implying in your first comment). How _wide_ do you want it to be?